# Symfony 3 DateTime from array conversion

Tags: php, datetime, symfony

In Symfony 3, I have the following object

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

/**
 * Shortcut
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shortcut", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_user_id", columns={"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_short", columns={"short"})})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Shortcut
    {
        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="creation", type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        private $creation;

         /**
         * Set creation
         *
         * @param \DateTime $creation
         *
         * @return Shortcut
         */
        public function setCreation($creation)
        {
            $this->creation = $creation;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get creation
         *
         * @return \DateTime
         */
        public function getCreation()
        {
            return $this->creation;
        }
    }
```

When I call getCreation() I have the date, so in twig I do

```
{{ shortcut.creation | localizeddate('medium', 'none', null) }}
```

but I receive

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion")
```

Because the format is an array and not an instance of DateTime, I have tested with `$shortcut->getCreation() instanceof \DateTime`

So I have tried to do

```
public function getCreation()
{
    return new \DateTime($this->creation);
}
```

but it awaits for a string...
Is it a problem with my database?

Comment: does http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html filter work ?

Comment: No... Same error, array to string. In fact there are no differences between the array and the DateTime format, except that the last one is an instance of DateTime, but contents is the same.

Comment: is this your full entity definition? Can it happen, that somewhere, accidentally you overwrite the field definition?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I have made a search on "creation" and that's the only occurence excepts the setter, I have added it the question

Comment: I have also added the uses etc. in case of

Answer (score 0):

Is the field actually populated in the database?

In the past I have used:
            "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",

Adding:

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
```

And then using the annotation like so to ensure it is populated on creation:

```
/**
 * @var datetime $created_date
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_date", type="datetime", options={"comment" = "Timestamp when the row was created"})
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 */
protected $createdDate;
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes the field is populated in the DB. If I well understand, your proposition is to use a class that will transform to a DateTime instance ? If so, isn't it possible to just modify the database ?

Comment: Yes it should be.  I am not overly familiar of what happens behind the scenes with this class, however if you are building a new system, it is handy to simply know that this field will always be populated correctly as the date when the entity was created.  If you are using existing data this may not be of much help as I don't believe it will modify existing data.  As in data being returned from the database.

Comment: Doctrine automatically creates the \DateTime instance when reading date or datetime fields. There should be something else here in the background.

Comment: Is it because you are accessing a private property in the twig template?
Try calling it from the getter: {{ shortcut.getCreation | localizeddate('medium', 'none', null) }}

Comment: How about using the date filter instead of localizeddate? e.g {{ shortcut.getCreation|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}

Answer (score 0):

So... Just to let you know. To my great and happy surprise, now it works!
I haben't change anything in relation to this and even came back to the original files and not be able to reproduce.
Let's say that's God intervention ;-) or caching problem, or whatever...

[EDIT] I have found! In fact it was something in my code... The date was not coming from DB but from a json file exported from DB. So now my problem is to display the date from the json... I'll look for it...

[EDIT2] solution for json is here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances.
Thanks to all who have spent time to help.